# azure bicep deploy of redis fails on consecutive deploys

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I am deploying a redis cache defined as

```
resource redis 'Microsoft.Cache/redis@2023-08-01' = {
  location: 'westeurope'
  name: 'name-redis'
  tags: {
    displayName: 'Redis'
  }
  properties: {
    redisVersion: '6.0'
    sku: {
      name: 'Standard'
      family: 'C'
      capacity: 0
    }
    enableNonSslPort: false
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
    redisConfiguration: {
      'maxmemory-reserved': '30'
      'maxfragmentationmemory-reserved': '30'
      'maxmemory-delta': '30'
    }
    updateChannel: 'Stable'
  }
}
```

The first time I deploy the bicep file it works fine, however on consecutive deploys the deployment fails with

```
{
  "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
  "target": "/subscriptions/x/resourceGroups/x/providers/Microsoft.Cache/redis/name-redis",
  "message": "The unknown resource response code 'NotModified' is encountered."
}
```

And the status for this resource gets `InternalServerError` in the portal.

I fail to understand the error message, and google did not find anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

> The unknown resource response code 'NotModified' is encountered: -

The above error occurs when the code is same as the existed without any changes been done. So, make sure that you have applied necessary changes to the Redis cache deployment properties for subsequent deployments.

Or the requirement is only the consecutive deployments without need of any changes, you need to pass  `--mode complete` argument along with the [az deployment group create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/deployment/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-deployment-group-create) command while deploying the resource.

*I tried the same code as you in my environment and the deployment was successful as shown below.*

```bash
param location string = resourceGroup().location
resource redis 'Microsoft.Cache/redis@2023-08-01' = {
  location: location
  name: 'redis'
  tags: {
    displayName: 'Redis'
  }
  properties: {
    redisVersion: '6.0'
    sku: {
      name: 'Standard'
      family: 'C'
      capacity: 0
    }
    enableNonSslPort: false
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
    redisConfiguration: {
      'maxmemory-reserved': '60'
      'maxfragmentationmemory-reserved': '30'
      'maxmemory-delta': '30'
    }
    updateChannel: 'Stable'
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: the deployment should be idempotent right ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found it hard to find the source of the internal server error. After getting a reponse from the bicep team that internal server error was to be regarded as provider specific errors I tried with a different definition for my resource. I tried this one https://github.com/azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.cache/redis-cache and then I don't have any issues anymore (withour using the `--mode complete`).